# Excel - Lookup between 2 sheets

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets on the same file, each sheet has 2 column,

first sheet is:

A name
B Phone

second sheet is:

A name
B Phone

What i need to be done is a formula that will lookup what phone numbers are **missing** in the second sheet. and mark those missing phone numbers on the first sheet.

thanks

Comment: You would do it the same as if they were in the same sheet, but reference the sheet name along with the cel.  Like : 'sheetA'!C12

Comment: So are you wanting to match the name columns and if phone is missing from sheet 2, then get the phone number from sheet 1 with the same name? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @MattCremeens what i need to know is what phone numbers are missing from one sheet to another. For example, if david 414811902 exist on 1st sheet but missing from the 2nd sheet i want it to be marked. The search is only by phone number

Comment: Or vice versa - i need to know what ohone numbers on 1st sheet also exist on the 2nd sheet. And be that, figure whixh people am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4,0),"X")
```

will mark a missing phone number with an "X" in the cell the formula resides.  This assumes that Sheet2 holds phone numbers in column C and the current sheet (maybe Sheet1) holds phone numbers in column A. Perhaps the formula is in column B on the current sheet and it gets copied down for each phone number in column A in the current sheet.